# Missing DLL Exception in F# Script loading from Azure CosmosDb

Tags: azure, f#

I'm trying to test some different queries in an F# script file against my Azure CosmosDb, but I'm getting an error regarding a missing DLL when I try to execute a query itself.

I'm loading the `Documents.Client.dll`:

```
#r "../packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB/lib/net45/Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.dll"
open Microsoft.Azure.Documents
open Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client
open Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq
```

But when I execute a query:

```
Seq.toList <| query {
            //some query that I copy & pasted from a working file
        }
```

I get this error:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ServiceInterop.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ServiceInteropWrapper.CreateServiceProvider(String configJsonString, IntPtr& serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.QueryPartitionProvider.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.QueryPartitionProvider.GetPartitionedQueryExecutionInfoInternal(SqlQuerySpec querySpec, PartitionKeyDefinition partitionKeyDefinition, Boolean requireFormattableOrderByQuery, Boolean isContinuationExpected)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Query.DocumentQueryExecutionContextBase.<GetPartitionedQueryExecutionInfoAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
```

(there is more in the stack trace - this is just the top of it).

I can't find the `ServiceInterop` dll anywhere - it's not referenced in any projects or in my packages folder, and it's not a nuget reference. I'm not sure what I could be missing to only get this error in F# Interactive.

**Update**

Following the advice in the comments from @tomislav-markovski, I changed the version of `Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB` to 1.13.2. This *does* create the `ServiceInterop` dll in the package folder, but now running my query in F# interactive gives this output:

```
--> Referenced 'c:\VSTS\MyApplication\../packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB/lib/net45/Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.dll' (file may be locked by F# Interactive process)


Script.fsx(5,1): error FS0229: Error opening binary file 'c:\VSTS\MyApplication\../packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDb/runtimes/win7-x64/native/Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ServiceInterop.dll': c:\VSTS\MyApplication\../packages/Micro
soft.Azure.DocumentDb/runtimes/win7-x64/native/Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ServiceInterop.dll: bad cli header, rva 0


Script.fsx(5,1): error FS3160: Problem reading assembly 'c:\VSTS\MyApplication\../packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDb/runtimes/win7-x64/native/Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ServiceInterop.dll': Exception of type 'Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.ErrorLogger+
StopProcessingExn' was thrown.
```

The "File may be locked" error seems like it's important, but I closed & reopened VSCode to make sure that instance of F# Interactive wasn't holding on to anything. I *am* referencing the Service Interop file:

`#r "../packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDb/runtimes/win7-x64/native/Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ServiceInterop.dll"`

If I remove this, the above errors go away... and I go back to the query itself crashing because of the missing DLL.

**Update 2**

I've tried a few additional things:

1. Absolute instead of relative pathing to the `Client.dll`. This results in the "missing service interop dll" error.
2. Absolute instead of relative pathing to the 'ServiceInterop.dll'. This results in the "error opening binary file" error.
3. Using `#I` to load the DLL with easier pathing:

   `#I "../packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB/lib/net45/"`

   `#r "Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.dll"`

   Results in the same "missing `ServiceInterop.dll`" error.
4. Simplifying the query:

   `Seq.toList <| query {
       for t in client.CreateDocumentQuery( documentCollectionUri()) do
       select t
   }`

This resulted in the same "missing `ServiceInterop.dll`" error.
5. Using FeedOptions with "Enable Cross Partiiton Query" on:

```
let feedOptions = FeedOptions()
feedOptions.EnableCrossPartitionQuery <- true
feedOptions.MaxItemCount <- 3 |> System.Nullable

Seq.toList <| query {
            for t in client.CreateDocumentQuery( documentCollectionUri(), feedOptions ) do
            select t
}
```

As you can see, I also tried setting the max item count. Both of these gave the same "missing `ServiceInterop.dll`" error.

Comment: Mind adding some client instantiation and query code? (minus keys). I seem to be able to connect to an instance fine.

Comment: Can you roll back the version to `1.13.2` and try this? There seems to be some bug that many people experience.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/262#issuecomment-304270332

Comment: Updated my post with some details after changing the version. I can add details about the query if you want, but it's super generic.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to a solution for this that I was able to find was to add the location of the ServiceInterop.dll to the Path environment variable for the duration of the FSI session, something like so:

```
open System
open System.IO

// get existing contents of path env var
let path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Path") 

// get location where nuget puts the service interop dll
let serviceInteropDir = @C:\User\<USERNAME>\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.documentdb.core\1.9.1\runtimes\win\native"

// add service interop location to the end of the path
let newPath = path + ";" + serviceInteropDir

// update the path env var with the new path
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", newPath)
```

NOTE: Notice I am using version 1.9.1 of the DocumentDB.Core package. [There seems to be a strong naming problem with the 1.10.0 version of the DocumentDB.Core package](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/483), so avoid that version until a fix is released or a workaround is found.